# Using jquery to make image bounce up and down in a looping animation

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I am new to jquery and want to create an effect of kids bouncing on a jumping castle (up and down motion) for a website I'm developing.

Below is a very cut down structure of the site. How do I make her move up and down as though she's on a jumping castle?

The id for the image is **ballerina**.

http://www.staging.alexanderdzine.com.au/jquery-test/

Comment: Assuming you want realistic physics, you would have to design a timeout loop in javascript and apply proper velocity for the image. If you would just like to have the movement, use jquery to change the position of the image step by step through a loop. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: Bounce effect exist in jquery UI http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/effect-bounce.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use this code...

```
var int=self.setInterval(function(){bounceIMG()},500);

function bounceIMG(){
   if($("#ballerina-wrapper").css('margin-top') == '0px'){
      $("#ballerina-wrapper").animate({
         marginTop: "30px"
      }, 150 );
   }    else {
      $("#ballerina-wrapper").animate({
         marginTop: "0px"
      }, 150 );
    }
}
```

Or use jquery ui bounce effect...